# Sending base64 emails with SWIFTMAIL

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am just trying to get my multipart emails encoded with base64 and send via swiftmail.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Email Template Test")
    ->setBoundary($boundary)
    ->setFrom(array('no-reply@domain.net' => 'Mailer Service'))
    ->setTo(array("a@d.com","a@b.com"))
    ->setBody($plaintext)
    ->addPart($htmlmail,"text/html");

$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding','base64');

$contenttype = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Type');
$contenttype->setValue('multipart/alternative');
```

As far as I can see from the documentation (which I don't find too clear), The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header is a text header, so i should be able to set it as above.  Before this, I ran an output of all the current headers, and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` was not listed in there, so It needed to be set.  Hence why in the above code I have tried to set it.

The output is fine, I get the emails, they work, but when I view source they are not encoded.  I have tried with the same above code but changing `$plaintext` to `base64_encode($plaintext)`, but just received the encoded message.  How is it done>

Answer (score 4):

In `version 5.4` you can set the encoder. Otherwise `Swift_Message` will use the native encoder to encode the message.

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance("Email Template Test");
$message->setEncoder(\Swift_Encoding::getBase64Encoding());
//...
```

Additionally there is a [bug (as of version 4 and 5)](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/69)  with encoding and `addPart`. Where the `MimePart` will not inherit the encoding from the origin message.
To do this you need to manually create the `MimePart` and attach it to the origin message.

```
$part = \Swift_MimePart::newInstance();
$part->setEncoder($message->getEncoder());
$part->setBody($htmlmail, 'text/html');
$message->attach($part);
```

This will automatically add the `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=****`, boundary `charset` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header information as well.

Result:

```
var_dump($message->toString());

string 'Message-ID: <2f48c04910b97f730834e92f268d3410@example.com>
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 20:45:30 +0000
Subject: Email Template Test
From: Mailer Service <no-reply@domain.net>
To: a@d.com, a@b.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1452804330_b0a47ad936ba98d2f513294958a235d0_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1452804330_b0a47ad936ba98d2f513294958a235d0_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBodG1sIG1lc3NhZ2U=

--_=_swift_v4_1452804330_b0a47ad936ba98d2f513294958a235d0_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRleHQgbWVzc2FnZQ==

--_=_swift_v4_1452804330_b0a47ad936ba98d2f513294958a235d0_=_--
' (length=751)
```

---

### SwiftMailer 6

In swiftmailer 6 the [`Swift_Encoding` class and `::newInstance()` methods were removed](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/v6.0.0/CHANGES#L4).

The original usage of `\Swift_Encoding::getBase64Encoding()`, looked like

```
public static function getBase64Encoding()
{
    return self::_lookup('mime.base64contentencoder');
}


private static function _lookup($key)
{
    return Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()->lookup($key);
}
```

Therefor you can call the [`mime.base64contentencoder`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/v6.0.0/lib/dependency_maps/mime_deps.php#L81) directly from the `Swift_DependencyContainer` instead.

```
$encoder = \Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()->lookup('mime.base64contentencoder');

$message = (new \Swift_Message("Email Template Test"))
    ->setEncoder($encoder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to do this myself recently, and

```
\Swift_Encoding::getBase64Encoding()
```

is apparently removed so I had to use Swift_DependencyContainer like this:

```
$message->setEncoder(\Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()->lookup('mime.base64contentencoder'));
```

Now swiftmailer will use base64 as the content transfer encoding.